# Sending data from Android activity to web form

Tags: java, android, httpclient

Im a newbie at android coding and I looked around a little to try to find a solution to my problem. The web-site I want to send the data has a form. I want to collect data from my activity in edittext fields and send it to the Web form and submit the web-form.

After some reading online I am across the below method. Can someone tell me if this is correct? If the webform has a field called "name" (I can access the site source). And the user enters "John Doe", So the NameValue pair will be "name","John Doe" right?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),10000);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", "value1"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", "value2")); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name3", "value3"));   
    // etc...
    try{
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new                InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are submitting the data via post.
Just in case you don't know this: You should post the data to the "form action" page.

Comment: If the web page source contains this for the form:

<form action="somefile.asp" method="post" name="somename" id="someid" onsubmit="return checkFields();">

then the I have to append somefile.asp to the end of my URL right?

Comment: exactly. You have to send the data to somefile.asp via post

Comment: Thanks. Will try that and post the result here

Comment: Sorry for posting back so late. Your advice worked. Thanks for the help buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what ever data you want to send you need to add to `nameValuePairs`

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Jhon Deo"));
```